# Run an NPM script from browsersync when a file changes

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, browser-sync, building

Hi I have a setup where I am build typescript file and then coping over the index.html file over to the build folder.

Browsersync is setup to watch the file, index.html located in the project's src/ folder. It's serving the index.html file out of the build folder.

I want to be able to change index.html file in the src folder, have a new build kicked off and see the update in the browser.

The setup needs to be things way, server our of build folder and developer from the src folder.

I want to keep things simple, using the TypeScript compiler, NPM script to run things and open to writing additional javascript code to accomplish things if Browsersync supports this.

I am not looking for some other build/setup solution.

Comment: How are you copying the `index.html` file? Post the `scripts` section of your `package.json`.